# Problems while checking if user purchases a subscription (add-on): empty array for appLicense.AddOnLicenses, weird extra sku object for product

Tags: windows, uwp, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm trying to add subscriptions to my app. And I have problems while checking if the user purchases a subscription. I have 2 problems:

1. Method `CheckIfUserHasSubscriptionAsync()` from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#code-examples) always return empty array after I bought a subscription (I tested either with and without trial). I can see that product has property `"IsInUserCollection":true` when calling method `GetSubscriptionProductAsync()`, but `appLicense.AddOnLicenses` inside `CheckIfUserHasSubscriptionAsync()` is always empty.
2. Method `GetSubscriptionProductAsync()` returns strange response with 1 extra sku.

In the documentation in the code comment it is written:

// Check if the first SKU is a trial and notify the customer that a trial is available.
// If a trial is available, the Skus array will always have 2 purchasable SKUs and the
// first one is the trial. Otherwise, this array will only have one SKU.

But actually I have always 3 purchasable SKUs after purchasing a product. And weird thing is that SKU that has the property `"IsInUserCollection": true` doesn't have any `SubscriptionInfo`:

```
[
  {
    "StoreId": "9NJJSGSS23P8",
    "IsInUserCollection": true,
    "Title": "1 год подписки",
    "ProductKind": "Durable",
    "Price": {
      "CurrencyCode": "USD",
      "FormattedPrice": "79,99 $",
      "FormattedBasePrice": "79,99 $",
      "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "79,99 $",
      "IsOnSale": false,
      "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
    },
    "HasDigitalDownload": false,
    "InAppOfferToken": "OneYearSubscriptionWithTrialFinal",
    "Skus": [
      {
        "StoreId": "9NJJSGSS23P8/0100",
        "Title": "1 год подписки",
        "IsInUserCollection": false,
        "IsTrial": false,
        "Price": {
          "CurrencyCode": "USD",
          "FormattedPrice": "79,99 $",
          "FormattedBasePrice": "79,99 $",
          "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "79,99 $",
          "IsOnSale": false,
          "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
        },
        "CollectionData": null,
        "IsSubscription": true,
        "SubscriptionInfo": {
          "BillingPeriod": 1,
          "BillingPeriodUnit": "Year",
          "HasTrialPeriod": false,
          "TrialPeriod": 0,
          "TrialPeriodUnit": "Week"
        },
        "Language": "ru"
      },
      {
        "StoreId": "9NJJSGSS23P8/0101",
        "Title": "1 год подписки",
        "IsInUserCollection": false,
        "IsTrial": false,
        "Price": {
          "CurrencyCode": "USD",
          "FormattedPrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedBasePrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "79,99 $",
          "IsOnSale": false,
          "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
        },
        "CollectionData": null,
        "IsSubscription": true,
        "SubscriptionInfo": {
          "BillingPeriod": 1,
          "BillingPeriodUnit": "Year",
          "HasTrialPeriod": true,
          "TrialPeriod": 1,
          "TrialPeriodUnit": "Week"
        },
        "Language": "ru"
      },
      {
        "StoreId": "9NJJSGSS23P8/0020",
        "Title": "1 год подписки",
        "IsInUserCollection": true,
        "IsTrial": false,
        "Price": {
          "CurrencyCode": "USD",
          "FormattedPrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedBasePrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "0,00 $",
          "IsOnSale": false,
          "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
        },
        "CollectionData": {
          "CampaignId": "",
          "StartDate": "2020-09-14T03:00:00.0000000",
          "EndDate": "2020-09-24T03:00:00.0000000",
          "AcquiredDate": "2020-09-14T12:26:28.7964538",
          "IsTrial": true,
          "TrialTimeRemaining": "10675199:2:48:05,4775807"
        },
        "IsSubscription": false,
        "SubscriptionInfo": null,
        "Language": "ru"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For the case when a product doesn't have a trial it has 2 skus, but with the same problem as mentioned above:

```
[
  {
    "StoreId": "9NVCL1M4W3MT",
    "IsInUserCollection": true,
    "Title": "TestSubscription9",
    "ProductKind": "Durable",
    "Price": {
      "CurrencyCode": "USD",
      "FormattedPrice": "0,00 $",
      "FormattedBasePrice": "0,00 $",
      "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "0,00 $",
      "IsOnSale": false,
      "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
    },
    "HasDigitalDownload": false,
    "InAppOfferToken": "TestSubscription9",
    "Skus": [
      {
        "StoreId": "9NVCL1M4W3MT/0100",
        "Title": "TestSubscription9",
        "IsInUserCollection": false,
        "IsTrial": false,
        "Price": {
          "CurrencyCode": "USD",
          "FormattedPrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedBasePrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "0,00 $",
          "IsOnSale": false,
          "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
        },
        "CollectionData": null,
        "IsSubscription": true,
        "SubscriptionInfo": {
          "BillingPeriod": 1,
          "BillingPeriodUnit": "Month",
          "HasTrialPeriod": false,
          "TrialPeriod": 0,
          "TrialPeriodUnit": "Week"
        },
        "Language": "en"
      },
      {
        "StoreId": "9NVCL1M4W3MT/0020",
        "Title": "TestSubscription9",
        "IsInUserCollection": true,
        "IsTrial": false,
        "Price": {
          "CurrencyCode": "USD",
          "FormattedPrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedBasePrice": "0,00 $",
          "FormattedRecurrencePrice": "0,00 $",
          "IsOnSale": false,
          "SaleEndDate": "9998-12-30T03:00:00.0000000"
        },
        "CollectionData": {
          "CampaignId": "",
          "StartDate": "2020-09-14T03:00:00.0000000",
          "EndDate": "2020-10-17T03:00:00.0000000",
          "AcquiredDate": "2020-09-14T12:58:24.8579557",
          "IsTrial": false,
          "TrialTimeRemaining": "10675199:2:48:05,4775807"
        },
        "IsSubscription": false,
        "SubscriptionInfo": null,
        "Language": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: For the second question, I checked the response data. I found that the last SKU is different from the others. The `IsSubscription` is false and it does not contain the `SubscriptionInfo` data. You could check it to see if the SKU is usable. For your first question, it looks like a server issue. I'd suggest you open a [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/) about this. Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic, and select in-app purchase for issue type.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, thank you for your response. I tried to contact support but I must pay at least 499$ to do it. I also created an issue at github, msdn forum, provided feedback on site, but no feedback yet. Will be helpful if you can suggest any other option or contact who can help with this problem.

Comment: The support ticket for the Store is free. Please use the link I posted.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I found that options contact us is paid (see on this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/JrlAH4g.png). Are you talking about it or something else?

Comment: The picture you shared shows the topics that supported. If you click on the title `payment and monetization`, you will see it shows some common questions. The support ticket for the store is free.